# Appium: Tap in iPhone4s and iPhone6s

Tags: ios, selenium, appium

In Appium, I'm using `tap(x,y)` for iPhone 4s. If I change the device to iPhone6, will the x and y coordinates change?

Comment: Why tag this with [tag:java]?

Comment: Removed excess, Reworded for clarity, Fixed typos. Removed incorrect java tag.

Answer (score 0):

No it should not get change if those x and y coordinates are not dependent on device. It should be in your app

Comment: I am not able to automate UIAPickerWheel using sendkeys(). So i'm using precise tap . Are you sure that it won't change?

Comment: As i said before, as long as you are using it within app it shouldn't get change.